# Backbone subview events

Tags: jquery, events, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a site developed with backbone. I have create an app and inside it I create some subview.

In this subview I can have a div (with id `close`) and if I click on it I have to trigger an event. But the event doesn't fire I don't know why. Can you explain me what I'm wrong with the event?

The problem is in `Search.Views.Product`, the subview with an event.

This is my app (I have cut something to read well the app):

```
//main app
Search.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        var this_app = this;
        this.subView = {
            Product : new Search.Views.Product({
                base_url:this_app.base_url || '',
                collection : new Search.Collections.Products()
            })
        }
    },
    render:function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            products:{
                wrap:"ul",
                id:"product-results",
                class:""
            }
        }
        var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
        this.renderProducts(settings);
    },
    renderProducts:function (settings) {
             $(this.id).html(this.wrap(this.subView.Product.getTemplate(settings.products.view), settings.products));
    }
});

//collection
Search.Collections.Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Search.Models.Product,
    initialize:function () {

    }
});

Search.Models.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: search.product.defaults || {},
    initialize:function () {

    }
});

Search.Views.Product = Backbone.View.extend({
    //doesn't fire this event!!!--------------------------------------
    events: {
        'click #close':  'closeResults',
         'click':  'closeResults'
    },
    closeResults:function (event) {
        console.log('Close results');
        $('#close').html('test');
    },

    getTemplate:function (view) {
        var data = this.collection.toJSON() || this.model.toJSON();

        data = this.normalize(data);
        var template = Handlebars.compile($(this.template).html());
        return template({view:view, results:data});
    },
    render:function () {
        // non utilizzato per ora
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the parent view element into the subview. Change this

```
        Product : new Search.Views.Product({
            base_url:this_app.base_url || '',
            collection : new Search.Collections.Products()
        })
```

to

```
        Product : new Search.Views.Product({
            el: this.$('.some-selector'),
            base_url:this_app.base_url || '',
            collection : new Search.Collections.Products()
        })
```

And in your subview replace the html of this.$el with the contents of the rendered template.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue #1**

ID's need to be unique.

Use a class instead. Change #close to .close in your markup and event bindings.

**Issue #2**

You are not setting the views $el in your render.  A Backbone view delegates all of its internal selector work to it's own el.

From Backbones source

```
$: function(selector) {
  return this.$el.find(selector);
},
```

You need to call render and it needs to set the el for event bindings to work.

```
 this.$el.html(...);
```

Comment: Okay.  Does the more general 'click' binding fire?